# Reading data from a text file into a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to read some data from a text file I created into a list, but keep getting the "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error when i try to do this.

Here is the code

```py
class Weather(): 
  """
  Weather Class 
  """
  def __init__(self,weather = ''): 
    self.weather= weather 
    
  def rome_weather(self, weather =''):
    """
    City temperature function 
    """
    #retrieving geocoding API to find longitude and latitude
    api = '66c622a1d43cb6e0010946bc5408b773'
    geo_url = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=Rome,IT&limit=2&appid={api}"
    request = urllib.request.urlopen(geo_url)
    result = json.loads(request.read())

    #defining longitude and latititude
    for value in result:
      for key in value:
        lon = value["lon"]
        lat = value["lat"]

    #retrieving current weather API
    weather_url = f"https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={api}"
    request2 = urllib.request.urlopen(weather_url)
    result2 = json.loads(request2.read())

    #temperature variable
    weather = result2['main']['temp'] - 273.15
    weather = round(weather,2)
    return f"{weather}\n"
    
weather= Weather()
for value in range(200):
  with open ('romeweather.txt','a') as f:
    f.write(str(weather.rome_weather(weather)))

rome=[]
with open ('romeweather.txt','r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if len(rome) <= 200:
      rome.append(float(line()))
```

A class is made with a function that calls the temperature of Rome, from an API. This info is then stored in a text file "romeweather.text". I need to store 200 lines of the data from that file into a list. The list part isnt working for me because the data is in the form of floats ex.15.67 on each line. I keep running into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 111, in <module>
    rome.append(float(line()))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Please let me know how I can make it work.

Comment: Did you read the error ? `line()` at least line, instead of `line`. You should REALLY learn to understand  a stacktrace, that will save you

Answer (score 1):

Line 111 should be as follows.

```
rome.append(float(line))
```

The problem was the `()` brackets that was causing python to try and call `line` when it was in fact a string.

Comment: wow I'm dumb, I didnt even notice that. Thank you!

Comment: Oversights happen to everyone. I recommend that you learn how to read stacktraces like @azro suggested.

Answer (score 1):

As has been previously said (and read by the error) you're trying to call a string, which is not callable. Simply remove the brackets on 'line()' and it will solve your problem.

```
rome.append(float(line))
```

Comment: @user99999 When I initially wrote my response, your answer was not present. I apologize.